# Why is there a lack of data and analysis of elastic range of PTFE (Teflon)?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, solid-mechanics, material-science

I am looking for the proportionality limit and elastic limit of PTFE (Teflon).
There are several papers which reported the mechanical behavior of PTFE in tensile test. However, almost all of those paper focus on the region where the engineering/true strain of PTFE is larger than 4 %.

I need information of the proportionality and elastic limit of PTFE so that the designed PTFE product would not go beyond those limits (expected to be around 1.5 %).

Is there any reason the elastic behavior of PTFE is not that significant? Or is there any information about the proportionality/elastic limit of PTFE (RT, cryogenics)?